# GUI for touchscreen panel

Tags: user-interface, qt4, touchscreen

I am planning to design an embedded device which will have atom processor platform and linux OS in it. It will have an 7" touchscreen panel. In stead of going for KDE and GNOME desktops I want to design my small desktop environment for the device. Can anyone please suggest which GUI tool I should use to design a desktop from scratch?

Comment: I would encourage you to accept answers to some of the 7 questions you previously asked, just to show you care.

Answer (score 0):

Why design a desktop from scratch? XFCE is small, pretty quick and ready to install on your device.

I really don't think there is a GUI tool to design a DE from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small touchscreen, you should avoid a desktop environment.
Because you don't have enough space for window management, and it's really difficult to fit everything in.

Instead, you should start a X server and launch an application with basic shortcuts (understand: big button). You could develop this kind of script with GTK2-perl or PyGTK in one hour.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I am planning not use window based GUI. As you suggested I will use the Big Buttons to launch applications(Like our iPod Touch and iPhone GUI). Can you please suggest me what I need to do develop such GUI in GTK2-Perl or PyGTK? Which tools I would need to do that? Please advice..

Comment: @Surjya : have you found your tools ? I'll suggest to use your favorite editor and run python or perl according to your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should seriously consider android as a pre-built, touch-friendly environment for your device. Yes, it requires a bit of hacking to get running on some random hardware, but it has had a lot of effort put into the UI, and provides a basic (and not so basic) set of pre-built applications for your device.